# How to insert multiple object detectors instead of choosing one bounding box

Tags: python, opencv, tracking, bounding-box

I am working on an algorithm with OpenVC to track multiple moving objects in a specific area of a video. At the moment the algorithm lets me choose the bbox in the first frame and than goes through the video. Now I need it to detect all of the objects on its own but dont know how to implement it

```
# Select the bounding box in the first frame
bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)
ret = tracker.init(frame, bbox)
```

this is the section i am running at the moment to track something in the video.

This is the whole code

```
tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()

# import the necessary packages
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import argparse
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import imutils
import time
import cv2

print("GeeksForGeeks")
print("Your OpenCV version is: " + cv2.__version__)

tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'MOSSE', 'CSRT']
tracker_type = tracker_types[5]

if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':
    tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerBoosting_create()
if tracker_type == 'MIL':
    tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
if tracker_type == 'KCF':
    tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
if tracker_type == 'TLD':
    tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerTLD_create()
if tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':
    tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
#if tracker_type == 'GOTURN':
   # tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
if tracker_type == 'MOSSE':
    tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMOSSE_create()
if tracker_type == "CSRT":
   tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()


# Get the video file and read it
vid_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('/Users/leonienelz/Downloads/capture_output60_countr02_1676545157.mp4')
ret, frame = vid_capture.read()


frame_height, frame_width = frame.shape[:2]
# Resize the video for a more convinient view
frame = cv2.resize(frame, [frame_width // 2, frame_height // 2])
# Initialize video writer to save the results
output = cv2.VideoWriter(f'{tracker_type}.avi',
                         cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), 60.0,
                         (frame_width // 2, frame_height // 2), True)
if not ret:
    print('cannot read the video')
# Select the bounding box in the first frame
bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)
ret = tracker.init(frame, bbox)
# Start tracking
while True:
    ret, frame = vid_capture.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, [frame_width // 2, frame_height // 2])
    if not ret:
        print('something went wrong')
        break
    timer = cv2.getTickCount()
    ret, bbox = tracker.update(frame)
    fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer)
    if ret:
        p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
        p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
        cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255, 0, 0), 2, 1)
    else:
        cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100, 80),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100, 20),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50, 170, 50), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100, 50),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50, 170, 50), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)
    output.write(frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if k == 27: break

vid_capture.release()
output.release()
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```